# Count number of button clicks

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to make a clicks counter with a button, that's my code.
I want to make a click counter, with the help of a button, which at each click, would display in a text box a number (1 then 2 ...) Can you help me?

```cs
private vous btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        int i = 0;
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
        break;
    }
    while (i < 10);
    {
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Help you with what? What are you expecting to happen, and how does the actual result differ from your expectations?

Comment: I would like to display in the textbox a number that corresponds to a counter of click on the button.
It would display a number from 1 to 10, one after the other.
Basically with each click I would like it to be 1 then 2, then 3, 4, ...
And when it gets to 10, start again at 0.

Comment: I'd recommend you start with fixing the compiler errors, then review the logic of your pointless `while` loop. Makes me wonder if you really want to print `i`, which is always 0. Please read [ask].

Comment: Move the i variable out of the method so it becomes a field of the class and retains its value between clicks.

Comment: How to do ? Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

Just to put you on the right track. The following displays from 1 to 10 and 'round again. ;-)

```
int x = 0;
void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = ++x.ToString();
    if(x==10) x=0;
}
```

Please try to learn some basics first.